# Why the App container is empty when a move my project in a subfolder using Vue js 2.5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vuejs2, vue-router, html-webpack-plugin

I built the project and moved it to a subfolder

the only changes

**/config/index.js**

```
'use strict'
// Template version: 1.3.1
 // see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.

  const path = require('path')

  module.exports = {
   dev: {

// Paths
  assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
  assetsPublicPath: '/',
  proxyTable: {},

// Various Dev Server settings
  host: 'localhost', // can be overwritten by process.env.HOST
  port: 8080, // can be overwritten by process.env.PORT, if port is in use, a free one will be determined
  autoOpenBrowser: false,
  errorOverlay: true,
  notifyOnErrors: true,
  poll: false, // https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-watchoptions-

// Use Eslint Loader?
// If true, your code will be linted during bundling and
// linting errors and warnings will be shown in the console.
 useEslint: false,
// If true, eslint errors and warnings will also be shown in the error overlay
// in the browser.
 showEslintErrorsInOverlay: false,

/**
 * Source Maps
 */

// https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development
 devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',

// If you have problems debugging vue-files in devtools,
// set this to false - it *may* help
// https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/options.html#cachebusting
   cacheBusting: true,

   cssSourceMap: true
  },

build: {
// Template for index.html
   index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),

// Paths
   assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
   assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
   assetsPublicPath: '/',

/**
 * Source Maps
 */

  productionSourceMap: false,
// https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#production
    devtool: '#source-map',

// Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
// Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
// Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
// npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
   productionGzip: false,
   productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],

// Run the build command with an extra argument to
// View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
// `npm run build --report`
// Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
   }
 }
```

using vue-router I setup the path

**/src/router/index.js**

```
 routes: [
    {
      path: './',
      name: 'Main',
      component: Main
    }
  ]
```

when I checked the subfolder it seems to loads the assets but the app container is empty

[image]

> I'm not sure if this is something that I should fix on vue or webpack

Comment: What does the /config/index.js contains? Your webpack config? Can you show it? What commands are you running to build/serve your app? From where do you run it? Do you have errors in the console?

Comment: Hey.. thanks for your comment !!...I just updated the question... and yes that file has the config for build and dev .. the commands are `npm run dev ` and `npm run build` ...I dont get any type or errors..

Comment: what did you move exactly and where? can you show your project structure now? And clearly show what changed.

Comment: I just create a folder inside dist call `test` and move all the content /dist/test/** then I create a local server using php `php -S localhost:8888` pointing to dist folder... so dist folder its my root when I go to localhost:8888/test/ it shows empty php ... the assets are loading but the components are not render.. <App> it's just empty

what I need is taking the `dist` folder and move it to a subfolder.. it could be one subfolder or nested folders like  /test/ or /test/test1/test2/test3/